# Delete unrelated records in one of some related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table `MainTable` with a column `MyField`. There are some tables related by foreign keys to `MainTable`. Their names are unknown.

I need:

- to find and delete all rows in `MainTable` which have no relation to any other table
- query should return all `MyField` values of these deleted rows

Or as an option: query should return all `MyField` values for rows which are to be deleted.

Thanks!

**UpDate1**
Sorry I forgot to say I use Sql Server 2005.
MainTable has PK.
Other tables have FK.

**Example**

```
create table MainTable
(
  ID int IDENTITY primary key,
  MyField nvarchar(256)
);

create table OtherTable1
(
    ID int IDENTITY primary key,
    MainTableID int foreign key references MainTable(ID)
);

create table OtherTable2
(
    ID int IDENTITY primary key,
    MainTableID int foreign key references MainTable(ID)
);

-- and so on

insert into MainTable (MyField) values('A');
insert into MainTable (MyField) values('BB');
insert into MainTable (MyField) values('CCC');
insert into MainTable (MyField) values('DDDD');
insert into MainTable (MyField) values('FFFFF');

insert into OtherTable1 (MainTableID) values(1);
insert into OtherTable1 (MainTableID) values(2);
insert into OtherTable2 (MainTableID) values(3);
```

Result i need:

1. MainTable

ID  MyField

4   DDDD

5   FFFFF

2. Query should return

A

BB

CCC

Comment: Are the other tables foreign-keyed to this one, or this table foreign-keyed to others? In other words: on which table is the foreign-key constraint?

Comment: Sorry Charlieface, I can't test it because I use Sql Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic SQL for this.

You can use the system views to pull out the foreign key information and build up a dynamic statement, either `SELECT` or `DELETE`.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT t.MyField
-- alternately DELETE t
FROM MainTable t
WHERE ' + (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(
        '
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ' t2.
    WHERE ' + c.ForeignKeys + ')
'
      AS nvarchar(max)), '
   AND '
      )
    FROM sys.tables MyTable
    JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk ON fk.referenced_object_id = MyTable.object_id
    JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT STRING_AGG('t2.' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = t.' + QUOTENAME(cMyTable.name), ' AND ')
        FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
        JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = fk.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
        JOIN sys.columns cMyTable ON cMyTable.object_id = MyTable.object_id AND cMyTable.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id
        WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    ) c(ForeignKeys)
    WHERE MyTable.name = 'MainTable'
);

PRINT @sql;  -- for testing

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0089d967e7ce002a752e935b71c5cf20)